# How to get "storage_sid" when using azurerm_storage_account to create a storage account using Active directory authentication

Tags: azure, terraform

I would like to create a storage account using the code below and join this storage account to AD.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageaccount" {
  name                     = var.azstorageaccount_name
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = var.account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.account_replication_type
  account_kind             = var.account_kind # FileStorage
  access_tier              = var.access_tier
  default_to_oauth_authentication = var.default_to_oauth_authentication
  large_file_share_enabled = var.large_file_share_enabled
  is_hns_enabled           = var.is_hns_enabled
  sftp_enabled             = var.sftp_enabled

  # Active Directory Domain Service
  azure_files_authentication {
    directory_type = "AADDS"
    active_directory {
      domain_name = "xxxxx.xxxxxx.com"
      domain_sid = "x-x-x-xx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
      domain_guid = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
      forest_name = "xxxxx.xxxxxx.com"
      storage_sid = "var.storage_sid"
      netbios_domain_name = "XXXXX"
    }
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.tag}"
  }
}
```

The official Terraform document states that **"storage_sid"** is required for this storage account to join AD.

[terraform doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account#azure_files_authentication)

Information about Active Directory was obtained through the "Get-ADDomain" command ("domain_name", "domain_sid", "domain_guid", "forest_name", "netbios_domain_name")

However, I couldn't find a way to know "**storage_sid**" before I created the storage account. If possible, is there a way to get "**storage_sid**" while creating a storage account? And is there a way to use it?

We desperately need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [azurerm_storage_account azure_files_authentication block · Issue |(github.com)](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12243)
one need to create the storage account via terraform.

***Code:***

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "exampageaccount"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  access_tier              = "Hot"
}
```

[image]

Then domain join needs to be done manually or using powershell commands:

```
[Join-AzStorageAccount ][3]
```

Only then then the generated sid can be referenced in the following code:

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "exampageaccount"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  access_tier              = "Hot"

  azure_files_authentication {
    directory_type = "AADDS"

    active_directory {
      domain_name         = "domainn.com"
      ....
      ....
      ....
      storage_sid = 
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Enable AD DS authentication for Azure file shares | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-enable#create-an-identity-representing-the-storage-account-in-your-ad-manually)